# intent getString error

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created two classes inside other class . inside these two classes i have used the `Intent` class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DurationsActivity.class );   
                     intent.putExtra("to",mydate);
```

in parent class i used this code to retrieve the intent value .

```
String to = getIntent().getExtras().getString("to");
String from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");
```

my logcat retriev this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: It seems that you set the "to" extra, but not the "from"

Comment: Post the full stacktrace so we know *where* this error is occurring. Also, it may be helpful for us to know *where* you are trying to retrieve the `Intent` extras (i.e. in an `Actiivty`, inside what method, etc...)

Comment: i try retrieve inside method inparent class

Comment: mydate might be null. Are you debugging??

Comment: Does parent class `extends Activity`? Stacktrace? Not enough information to help you. The possibilities are endless without more info

Comment: depends on what is null, `getIntent()` or `getExtras().getString()` a tip: when you set from & to, with non-string variables or values then `getString()` will be null, getInt or getDouble() might be the correct methods... so based on the dataType you set, you have to use proper `getXXX()`

Comment: Here in your example you set intent.putExtra("to",mydate); only if this is only you have done then you get nullPointer from   String from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from"); this line.

Comment: my my date is not null , but i think my problem in Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customfrom.class ) , need to be more specefic with getApplicationContext() it most be a class but eclipse give me error on that parameter... remove arguments to match intent .

Answer (score 0):

mydate is like a key to identify the value in intent.

Declare mydate :-

```
 String mydate,mydate1;

 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, DurationsActivity.class );   //Be Specific
                 intent.putExtra("to",mydate); 
                intent.putExtra("from",mydate1);
```

Than in DurationActivity.class
  You can use your usual code in onCreate to get the contents from previous activity:-

```
 String to = getIntent().getExtras().getString("to");
 String from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try, hope it will work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, DurationsActivity.class );   
                 intent.putExtra("to",""+mydate);
```

String to = getIntent().getExtras().getString("to");

String from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");